# Blocks administration page is slow

Tags: blocks

Devel query log shows too many highlighted same queries, like

```
UPDATE block SET module=:db_update_placeholder_0,
delta=:db_update_placeholder_1, theme=:db_update_placeholder_2,
status=:db_update_placeholder_3, weight=:db_update_placeholder_4,
region=:db_update_placeholder_5, custom=:db_update_placeholder_6,
visibility=:db_update_placeholder_7, pages=:db_update_placeholder_8,
title=:db_update_placeholder_9, cache=:db_update_placeholder_10
WHERE  (bid = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
```

[image]

Are there any suggestions that I can solve this problem?

Comment: How big is your block table? How many themes you have installed?

Comment: @Mołot installed only one theme, block table size is 48KB

Comment: So it's still on it's minimum size, the one it gets on fresh install. It means most of the problems with adding and deleting entries does not apply to you. Weird.

Comment: @Mołot I truncated the Block table and reconfigure blocks. It didn't help, requests exist, but I think the page is loading much faster.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but I'm afraid you might need to hire a contractor. Something strange is happening and without serious debug it will be hard to tell what.

Comment: @Mołot Thanks for your reply. Requests exist only on the Blocks page, that's why I ended up with solving it later someday..

Comment: Post here some details about the site configuration. Do you use any modules that alter/extend the block functionality? Any custom modules?